# Idea behind displaying probability mass functions by impulses

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I usually saw the "probability mass function" graphs like this graph which is from [Probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function):

[image]

Graphs like above one simply connect each possible value of a random variable to its probability. But recently, in [Probability, Random Variables and Stochastic Processes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071226613) I saw graphs like this:

[image]

As you can see, in above graph each possible value of a random variable is connected to its probability with an arrow which reminds impulses. I want to know what is the idea for using arrows in displaying PMF rather than a simple line segment? Is that related to the properties of `Dirac delta`, `impulses` or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On one hand, it's just a diagram. But here is a link of sorts, maybe you'll like it:

It's not an impulse in the physical sense. However, if you think about probability distributions as *measures* (which you'll eventually have to if you pursue probability far enough) then discrete probability distributions like this are weighted sums of *Dirac measures*. If you don't know what a measure is, then I'll describe them quickly like this: A measure is a way to assign a general notion of volume to a set. In probability theory, we assign the "probability" to a set, and think of more probably events as having more volume, as having a larger measure. A probability distribution is just a way to "measure" the events that occur in terms of how "likely" they are.

The Dirac measure is written $\delta_x$ for some $x\in\Bbb R$ (or $\Bbb R^n$, whatever) and it is the measure that acts like this: $$\delta_x(A):=\begin{cases}1&x\in A\\0&x\notin A\end{cases}$$

Where $A$ is any 'event' (usually, a Borel subset of $\Bbb R^{(n)}$). Intuitively it's the measure that says: the value $x$ is almost surely going to occur, and the probability of an event $A$ is determined entirely by whether or not it contains $x$. For the dice roll example that seems to appear in your picture (I assume $10,20,\cdots,60$ are the values) the measure is this: $$\mu=\sum_{k=1}^6\frac{1}{6}\cdot\delta_{10k}$$

For example, the measure of $A:=(0,35)$ (read: the probability of the event $0<X<35$) is $\sum_{k=1}^6\frac{1}{6}\delta_{10k}(0,35)$ and the summands there are determined by whether or not $0<10k<35$: this is when $k=1,2,3$ only, so we get $0+\frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=1}^3(1)=3/6=1/2$ as you expect.

This is similar to the Dirac delta "function" in physics or distribution theory since: $$\int_\Bbb R f\,\mathrm{d}\delta_x=f(x)$$For any (measurable) $f$, where the integral is understood as a Lebesgue integral against the measure $\delta$. This equation of course resembles the more informal: $$\int_\Bbb R f(t)\delta_x(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\overset{?}{=}f(x)$$Where we pretend that $\delta_x$ is some kind of integrable function.

I think of probability masses a bit like impulses in the following sense: "watch" the cumulative distribution function "evolve" over time, i.e. plot $F(t)$ as $t$ increases. For discrete distributions you'll see "spikes/impulses/peaks" etc. whenever $t$ crosses one of those values in the range, and the jump's magnitude will correspond to the probability of that value being attained.